# Sound editing in flash

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

Is there any way to make a flash sound editing application with Action Script ?
I'm pretty sure that there is no way around that but i want to make sure . also if not then as a relevant can i use flex to do that . if not then i have to ask what to use to do that . I'm planning to publish that over the web . 
thanks in advance .  and forgive my ignorance

Comment: Yes, you can make a sound editing App w/ ActionScript.  I know at least three people who have done so to some extent.  Digimix is one of the more popular ones ( http://blog.arsthanea.com/2007/09/21/digimix-adobe-air-application/ ).  It was moderately promoted as an awesome use of Adobe AIR during the early days of AIR 1.  However, without knowing what you want to do; it is hard to qualify ActionScript as a good choice.  I Voted to close.

Comment: let's say i want to make an application to cut sounds ... can it be done with action script or it requires other language like flex or any thing .. ?

Comment: Flex is an ActionScript Framework, primarily for building applications.  Anything that can be done in Flex can be done in ActionScript.  That said; I assume you can cut sounds in AS3; I just don't personally have experience trying to do so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can!
Use [flash.media.Sound.extract](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Sound.html?filter_flex=4.1&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6#extract%28%29) to get raw data and modify it however you want.
Small example from docs:

```
    function processSound(event:SampleDataEvent):void
    {
    var bytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
    sourceSnd.extract(bytes, 4096);
    event.data.writeBytes(upOctave(bytes));
    }
    function upOctave(bytes:ByteArray):ByteArray
    {
         var returnBytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
        bytes.position = 0;
        while(bytes.bytesAvailable > 0)
        {
            returnBytes.writeFloat(bytes.readFloat());
            returnBytes.writeFloat(bytes.readFloat());
            if (bytes.bytesAvailable > 0)
            {
                bytes.position += 8;
            }
        }
        return returnBytes;
    }
```

Also you may want to use [flash.media.SoundTransform](http://help.adobe.com/ru_RU/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/SoundTransform.html) if you want some simple transformations.

Comment: Ooops .. im stuck please some one tell me can or cant and please link the library or the method with a demo if you can ..

Comment: if you follow [this link](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Sound.html?filter_flex=4.1&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6#extract%28%29) you'll see an example